# How to get data from forms?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

How can I get data from a form (`ProductCreateForm`)?

If I write `form = self.get_form()`, then I just get a form template, where some data is selected, and some are not (select especially).

If I write `form = ProductCreateForm(request.POST)`, then I get an error saying that the request was not found. Perhaps this is due to the fact that I set the request in get_context_data() and work with them in the `__init__` method in the `forms.py`.

I process the data in the clean method in the `forms.py`.

I have the following **view**

```
class ProductsCreate(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductCreateForm
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(ProductsCreate, self).get_initial()
        initial['request'] = self.request

        return initial
​
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx=super(ProductsCreate, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['special_form'] = SpeciallyPriceForm()

        return ctx
​
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None

        if kwargs.get('slug'):
            category = Category.objects.filter(slug=kwargs.get('slug')).first()
            self.initial.update({'category': category})

        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form = ProductCreateForm(request.POST)     #What here?
        special_form = SpeciallyPriceForm(self.request.POST)
​
        if form.is_valid() and special_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

**forms**

```
class ProductCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #....
​
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('initial').get('request')
        super(ProductCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #...
        user = self.request.user
        provider = Provider.objects.filter(user=user.id).last()
        self.fields['category'] = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=provider.category.all())
        #...

   def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ProductCreateForm, self).clean()
        cd_category = cleaned_data.get('category')
        #...
​
​
class SpeciallyPriceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SpeciallyPrice
        fields = ['adittional_specially_price', 'adittional_specially_number']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.try pass request in that way

```
def get_initial(self):
    """
    Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
    """
     initial = super(ProductsCreate, self).get_initial()

    initial['request'] = self.request

   return initial
```

then in forms.py

```
    def __init__(self):
         kwargs.pop('initial').get('request')
```

2. Are you sure that is working at all? On **init** in your forms I don't see super() call so you should get an error?
3. Do you have problem only with category field the rest data you get properly?
4. Where do you pass it kwargs.pop('request') ??
5. You can print and check what is in self.request.POST

Comment: `def get_initial(self):` - this function must be in ProductsCreateForm in forms.py?

Comment: CreateView, but all working well for you except you don't get the data? With your code you get request in forms.py ?

Comment: In the `self.request.POST` I get all data from all form.

Comment: Updated code: add `def of initial request` in **views.py** and changed __init__ in forms.py

Comment: I tried to determine the `form` in the method in `post` method. But I get error - `initial`

Comment: form(request.POST ,initial={'request': request}), then print if form is valid or not, maybe django gives you info that form is invalid

Comment: if all data you get and form is bound then try print(form.errors) if that don;t show you what going on then my knowledge is too small to help you

Comment: I write `form = ProductCreateForm(request.POST, initial={'request': request})`, then `print(form)` and get template of form with inputed data.

Comment: Did it pass ? Is it valid or invalid? Did it save in database? What is going on now?

Comment: It'is invalid. form.errors printed `<ul class="errorlist"><li>image<ul class="errorlist"><li>Upload image</li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: Thnx for help. I will try to deal further with the form already)

Comment: Add to forms with that field imgage request.FILES your_form_with_img(request.POST, request.FILES)

Comment: Very Thnx for help)